# Architecture Direction Help: Creating an Azure Active Directory PAM Module

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, pam

I'm interested in creating a Linux Pluggable Authentication Module (PAM) that authenticates against Azure Active Directory. It appears that Oauth 2.0 is what Microsoft uses for this.

In reviewing the [Authentication Scenarios](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/) it seems that the "Daemon or Server Application" probably makes the most sense, but I'm not positive. "Native Application to Web API" might also be a possibility, but all the app flows given show kicking off a pop-up browser instance to authenticate, which doesn't seem possible in PAM. As a result, unless I'm scrapping responses that flow doesn't appear to work, and scrapping responses seems like a bad idea.

My questions:

1. What is the best way to validate a user's credentials for this scenario? Is a Daemon or Native App?
2. What is the rough flow I would be looking at to do this? (e.g. If I'm using a Daemon, what calls do I make to validate the user creds?)
3. Any idea on what this looks like if 2FA is enabled for a user?

Thank-you for your help. I feel like none of the available options really fit here, and want to make sure I'm heading the right direction until I invest a bunch of time in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bureado's PAM you point to uses what's known as the OAuth "Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant".  It basically takes the user's username & password and passes them to Azure AD for authentication.  It has a bunch of limitations, several of which Vittorio describes [here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/).  A core problem you pointed out is that MFA does not work.

For scenarios like this Azure AD also supports the OAuth "Device Profile Flow".  There's a code sample here that shows how to do it in .NET: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-deviceprofile. I'd recommend going that route.

Comment: Thank-you. This confirmed what I thought, and provides all the information I need.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the following module that appears to mostly do what I'm looking to do anyway:

https://github.com/bureado/aad-login

He chose to use "Native App". I'm still not positive if this is the "best option" and therefore I'm going to leave this open to other answers. I'd love it if someone could explain why this is the best option.

Meanwhile, I'm now trying to get AAD group memberships to be imported in like pam_ldap, or pam_kerberos, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how that's supposed to work, and have posted another question:

[How to write a PAM module which changes group membership?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39802215/how-to-write-a-pam-module-which-changes-group-membership)

Should anyone come across this later and want to do the same thing, we're planning on open sourcing the final modified solution with this extended functionality. It doesn't do it yet, but the code is on GitHub here:

https://github.com/CyberNinjas/aad-login